# How to find properties of time varying voltage?

Tags: voltage

[image: My question is in the photo] I need to find amplitude and phase angle of 5th harmonic component. But I can't understand how to do that. I have already calculated amplitude for 1st harmonic component. My calculation is as follows. [image: calculation for the 1st harmonic component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the integrals with \$\small sin(5\omega t)\$ and \$\small cos(5\omega t)\$ replacing \$\small sin(\omega t)\$ and \$\small cos(\omega t)\$, respectively. The amplitude of the \$\small 5^{th}\$ harmonic is then: \$\small \sqrt{a_5^2+b_5^2}\$ and the phase angle is: \$ \small\phi_n= arctan\large \left (\frac{b_5}{a_5}\right)\$

In general, the amplitude and phase angle of the \$\small n^{th}\$ harmonic are:
 $$\small A_n=\sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2}$$ and: $$\small \phi_n = \small arctan \left (\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)$$.

To see why this is so, consider the simple case: \$\small y(t)= A sin(\omega t+\phi)\$, which may be written: $$\small y(t)= Acos(\phi)\:sin(\omega t)+Asin(\phi)\:cos(\omega t)$$

Now, doing the Fourier integral gives:
$$\small a_1= Acos(\phi) $$ 
$$\small b_1= Asin(\phi) $$
Hence:$$ \small A= \sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}$$
$$ \small tan(\phi)= \left (\frac{b_1}{a_1}\right)$$

We can easily expand this analysis to the \$\small n^{th}\$ harmonic giving:
$$\small A_n=\sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2}$$
$$ \small tan(\phi_n)= \left (\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)$$

Comment: Is the only thing which I have to do is applying 5wt instead of wt? What will be the range for integration? 0 to T/2 and T/2 to T or other one. Please can you explain me?

Comment: Same range of integration. You'll find that the 5'th harmonic is 1/5 'th of the fundamental, as the integral of sin(5wt) is -1/5 cos(wt)

Comment: Then should I integrate the function from 0 to T/2 in one time and other time T/2 to T. But the second half is zero. So do I have to integrate only sin(5wt) and cos(5wt) for that range only?

Comment: Same range of integration for all harmonics, only sin(nwt) changes  . Slight error in the above btw ... 5'th harmonic is 1/5 'th of the fundamental, as the integral of sin(5wt) is -1/5 cos(5wt)

Comment: Is there should be - term for sin term before integrating?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; it's \$\int {y(t) \:sin(n\omega t)\:d\omega t}\$,  \$\int {y(t) \:cos(n\omega t)\:d\omega t}\$, etc...

Comment: You're welcome.